# Key Pair or Oauth configuration for snowflake service accounts

Tags: security, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, service-accounts

I have gone through below document in snowflake, talking about securing service accounts.

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-service-account-security-part-2/

Could you please let us know if any one use "Key Pair" or "Oauth" configuration for service accounts.
In our case, we are using service accounts to connect ETL to snowflake.

It will grateful if any one can help me to secure service accounts in snowflake.

Regards,
Srinivas.

Answer (score 0):

For Kaypair authentication - it depends on the driver/connector, the ETL application is using to connect Snowflake. Below are a couple of links.

1. [JDBC KeyPair Authentication](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#using-key-pair-authentication)
2. [ODBC KeyPair Authentication](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#using-key-pair-authentication)
3. [Python Connector Authentication](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-key-pair-authentication)
4. [Spark COnnector Authentication](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#using-key-pair-authentication)

For OAuth - You need to select [Oauth Server](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth.html#oauth) for generating the Token. You can then use the token in the [connection string](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-intro.html#oauth-with-clients-drivers-and-connectors) for your connection.